# Adjusting code to output a list of lists regardless of inputs

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

I'm trying to pose this question a little differently since I have not been able to come up with a solution.

I have a code that outputs a list of lists. The output is dynamic meaning it can change depending on user input.

here is the code i use to produce the list of lists given three arrays:

```
Arr1 = [9,7,3,1]

Arr2 = [[14,6],[13,2]]

Arr3 = [0,2]

Z = np.array([[Arr1[i]] if not np.sum(Arr3 == i) else Arr2[i] for i in np.arange(Arr1.size)], dtype=object)

Z = [[list([14, 6])], [list([7])], list[([13, 2])], list[([1])]]
```

The code replaces certain elements in a list with an array based on indices given in another array (arr 3).

When the condition i = Arr3 is not met (say Arr3 was empty) and it just reverts to the original array the output of this code gives:

```
Z = [[9][7][3][1]]
```

which is sometimes the case given the inputs to produce the list.

Now i need to use a for loop to iterate over each sub list. Say just Z[0] for an example. I need to pull the list from index zero and iterate over those elements (regardless of the size of Z[0]).

**Here is my issue:**

For description of the issue, case 1 will be the situation when the output looks like this:

```
Z = [[list([14, 6])], [list([7])], list[([13, 2])], list[([1])]]
```

and case 2 will be when the output looks like this:

```
Z = [[9][7][3][1]]
```

For case 1, Z[0] looks like this:

```
[list([14,6])]
```

When I attempt to iterate this over a function using a for loop (say for i in Z[0]:) i get the error (can only concatenate list (not "float") to list).

for case 2 the output looks like this:

```
Z = [[9][7][3][1]]

Z[0] = [9]
```

And with that the code to iterate over the list works. However I need to work for case 1 as well

IF I remove brackets from this line of code here:

```
Z = np.array([[Arr1[i]] if not np.sum(Arr3 == i) else Arr2[i] for i in np.arange(Arr1.size)], dtype=object) 

remove brackets around [Arr1[i]]
--->

Z = np.array([Arr1[i] if not np.sum(Arr3 == i) else Arr2[i] for i in np.arange(Arr1.size)], dtype=object)
```

Then

```
Z = [list([14,6]),list([7]),list([13,2]),list([1])]

and
z[0] = [14,6]
```

and the code to iterate over the list works! But, then it does not work for case 2, because the output looks like

```
[9 7 3 1]

Z[0] = 9
```

and I get the error 'float' object is not iterable.

Does anyone know a fix to this? How i can get the output to look right regardless of the input?

Comment: I think you want to flatten each list.  There's quite a few questions/answers on here for that.

Comment: @jeffUK if i flatten the list always though, then for case 2 for Z[0] i end up with a float again and get an error when trying to iterate. Is there a way I can have an if statement to handle that?

Comment: I'm struggling a little to see what you're trying. to do.. Could you just narrow your question down to 'With this lists: [[1],[2],[3]]  I want X output,  and with this list [[[14, 6], [7], [13, 2], [1]]] Y output?

Comment: I think the answer might be 'don't get yourself in a situation where you have to deal with two different data structures and not know which'.  i.e. change it so if your condition is not met, you get `None` and and go deal with that separately.